# Как сгенерировать php хеш в 1 символ из 40 символов?

Tags: php

Суть в том, что нужно получить 1 букву из алфавита и цифр на основе некоей строки

Пробовал брать первый символ мд5/sha512 - первый символ не охватывал все 40 символов, было около 15

Comment: вообще сами алгоритмы md5/sha512 дают двоичную строку с 256 значениями на байт. Если у вас "выходило около 15", то вы использовали шестнадцеричное представление хеша. Попробуйте использовать http://php.net/manual/ru/function.hash.php с параметром $raw_output=true. получите двоичные данные, их вы можете перевести например в base64. правда в нем есть два дополнительных символа кроме букв и цифр

Comment: а что за алфавит вместе с цифрами образует набор в 40 символов? русский 31+10, либо 33+10. латиница 26+10.